# SQL copy and upadate table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql table with the name oc_product_to_category

example of sql table.

```
product_id category_id


1          146

2          146

..         146

16         147

17         147

...        ...

1800      191
```

So my question is how i can copy table and change and change only the `category_id`?

So my result need to be like this.
example of sql table nedded result

```
product_id category_id

1          146

1          200

2          146

2          200

..         146

..         200

16         147

16         260

17         147

17         260

...        ...

1800      191

1800      291
```

Sorry for bad explanation but i cant import image.

INSERT INTO oc_product_to_category ( category_id) SELECT "147" FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE category_id = 146

I was traying with somtheihng like this but i get error Duplicate enrty 147 - 0 for key PRIMARY

Answer (score 2):

Create an exact copy including indexes of your table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

Then insert with

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT whatever_the_logic_is_for_your_new_data FROM old_table;
```

If you don't want to include indexes and foreign keys constraints and what not, you can also do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT whatever_the_logic_is_for_your_new_data FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying table you can use the following query :

```
Select * Into [NewTable] From oc_product_to_category
```

then you have to update the table but I dont know exactly where number 200 and 260 come from
If they are already in table so you dont have to update just add an Order by  clause in your select from that table , if they are not in the table then you have to add.
please be more specific what you are going to update